# How to fix Wikipedia table pulled into Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wikipedia

I have a script which uses Beautiful Soup to pull a Wikipedia table from a specified article, and then I have that table inserted into a Python DataFrame. The problem comes from Wikipedia's formatting, where the HTMl does not return shared values on each row, so when two consecutive rows have the same value in a column, it only returns the first instance.

The result is an output similar to this below.

```
       Date        |   Random Field   |   State   |   Random Field   |   Source 
Friday, June 1st   |       text       |     WY    |       text       |    [12] 
      text         |       text       |    [13]   |       NaN        |    NaN
Friday, June 8th   |       text       |     VT    |       text       |    [14] 
      text         |        CA        |    text   |       [15]       |    NaN
```

In the second row, that entry shares both the date and state, resulting in two NaN values at the end. In the fourth row, that entry only shares a date value.

The goal is to iterate through the DataFrame finding values for Date and State which are not as expected (i.e. not Dayofweek, Month # for date or XY for state), and when anomalies are found copy the value from above and shift the cells appropriately to return an output as follows.

```
       Date        |   Random Field   |   State   |   Random Field   |   Source 
Friday, June 1st   |       text       |     WY    |       text       |    [12] 
Friday, June 1st   |       text       |     WY    |       text       |    [13]
Friday, June 8th   |       text       |     VT    |       text       |    [14] 
Friday, June 8th   |       text       |     CA    |       text       |    [15]
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, let alone efficient. I know I could do it in Excel but would prefer to stay within Python for ease of building a processing pipeline when more table may be needed.

Thanks so much for any guidance!

Edit: Per request below adding the details of how the DataFrame was made in case that helps.

```
with io.open('Wiki article', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(article)

for caption in soup.find_all('caption'):
    if "CAPTION TEXT" in caption.get_text():
        ths = table.find_all('th')
        headings = [th.text.strip() for th in ths]
        table = caption.find_parent('table')

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0])
```

Comment: This question could use the functions you're using to convert from beautifulsoup to pandas df in order for us to help! I expect this has more to do with the specific function being used to convert to dataframe, rather than the pandas dataframe itself (there should be no inherent restrictions for dataframes, unless you are using that column as the index). This can easily be worked around by assigning your own index (e.g. i = 0,1,2...), but that may need to be done in your conversion

Comment: Just added the functions for the steps from loading the article, to scanning it with BeautifulSoup, to loading it into a DataFrame. The Wikipedia tables use rowspan on columns values shared across rows as seen by the table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Getaway_World_Tour#Tour_dates